# Solve system of nonlinear equation in Python

Tags: python, solver

I am experiencing an issue in solve system of 3 equation of 3 unknowns using python.
I used many optimization methods to find the unknowns but still the error I am getting with the desired angles is very big.

Here are the 3 equations.

```py
Vcos2nu = (0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2 - 0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2)/(0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2 + 0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2)

Vsin2nu = 2*Abs(-0.5*sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - 0.5*cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))*Abs(-0.5*sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - 0.5*cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))/(0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2 + 0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2)

Vdelta = arg(-cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) - cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))
```

and here are the values for each the 3 equations,

```
Vcos2nu = -0.28543
Vsin2nu = -0.13766479
Vdelta  = -0.94906616
```

I want to get the optimal theta3, theta4, theta5, could anyone assist?
I am getting values of theta3, theta4, theta5 in a way if I replace them back into the equations I am getting big error values between Vcos2nu calculated and Vcos2nu_given, similarly for Vsin2nu and Vdelta.

I tried several optimization methods

- differential evolution method
- basinhopping
- minimize functions

.. but nothing worked to improve the error values

Comment: You haven't shown us any of your code.  It's possible that there are no inputs that give those outputs, but we can't tell if you've done it right.  And what's `arg`?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to optimize the difference between the 3 variables: Vcos2nu, Vsin2nu, Vdelta. To optimize the difference you can compute the distance as:

```
loss = (Vcos2nu - Vdelta)**2 + (Vsin2nu - Vdelta)**2 + (Vcos2nu - Vsin2nu)**2
```

That formula will give you the overall difference and a measurable loss function to be optimized. Your goal is to reduce the loss to 0. You can make use of different algorithms.

If you want to go deep in math you should compute the derivative of the loss function and equal to zero, so you can solve a 3 parameter equation and find the optimal values for the parameters.

There are other ways to solve it. You can use a `GeneticAlgorithm`, `GradientDescentAlgorithm` or other optimization algorithms to obtain the values. To do so you must build a loss function:

```
def loss_function(theta3, theta4, theta5):
    Vcos2nu = (0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2 - 0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2)/(0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2 + 0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2)
    Vsin2nu = 2*Abs(-0.5*sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - 0.5*cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))*Abs(-0.5*sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - 0.5*cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))/(0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2 + 0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2)
    Vdelta = arg(-cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) - cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))
    return (Vcos2nu - Vdelta)**2 + (Vsin2nu - Vdelta)**2 + (Vcos2nu - Vsin2nu)**2
```

Finally, launch a Local Search algorithm, for example.

```
from numpy import sin, cos, pi, sqrt
from numpy import abs as Abs
from numpy import angle as arg

def fitness_function(theta3, theta4, theta5):
    Vcos2nu = (0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2 - 0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2)/(0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2 + 0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2)
    Vsin2nu = 2*Abs(-0.5*sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - 0.5*cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))*Abs(-0.5*sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - 0.5*cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + 0.5*cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))/(0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2 + 0.25*(-sin(2*theta4 + pi/4) + sqrt(2)*cos(2*theta4) - cos(2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))**2)
    Vdelta = arg(-cos(-2*theta3 + 2*theta4 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta3 - 2*theta4 + pi/4) - cos(-2*theta4 + 2*theta5 + pi/4) + cos(2*theta4 - 2*theta5 + pi/4))
    return (Vcos2nu - Vdelta)**2 + (Vsin2nu - Vdelta)**2 + (Vcos2nu - Vsin2nu)**2
# Initialize the starting point for the search
x = [1, 2, 3]
# Set the step size and the number of iterations
step_size = 0.1
num_iterations = 10000
# Run the local search algorithm
for i in range(num_iterations):
    # Generate a random perturbation vector
    perturbation = [random.uniform(-step_size, step_size) for i in range(3)]
    # Add the perturbation to the current point
    new_x = [x[i] + perturbation[i] for i in range(3)]
    # If the new point is better than the current point, update the current point
    if fitness_function(*new_x) < fitness_function(*x):
        x = new_x
    # Print the value of J for each iteration
    print("Iteration:", i+1, " loss:", fitness_function(*x))
# Print the final values of the parameters and the final value of J
print("Final parameters:", x)
print("Final distance:", fitness_function(*x))
# Final parameters: [1.3620091174531106, 1.7123170789841664, 3.3255052386042485]
# Final distance: 1.000000000004063
```

If you are not happy with the results, try launching different parameters or algorithms.

DISCLAIMER: 1. I don't know what is arg. I imported a numpy function that does the same. If it is other thing, import your implementation of arg properly and launch my code. 2. Maybe there is no optimal solution to your problem.

I hope I helped.